# Checking player is not in scene(Not working)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game that I want a restart button to appear if you die (The game object destroys itself).

This is what I have. This is the script attached to the button:

```
public GameObject Player;
public GameObject Button;
bool player;

public void RestartGame(){
    SceneManager.LoadScene("SampleScene");
}

void Start(){
    player = true;
}

void Update(){
    if (!Player){
        player = false;
    }

    if(player == true) {
        Button.SetActive(false);
    }
    if(player == false){
        Button.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

And this is the code attached to the object that gets deleted:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

When it starts the Button is disabled but when I die nothing appears. I have tried many things like checking if it is `== null` and all of that stuff but it still doesn't work. My goal is to make the restart button appear once the object is destroyed.

Comment: when player die, you destroyed it ? can you show the code about this?

Comment: void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

Comment: this "gameObject" is Player ? and this code is in this class ? or other class?

Comment: I have attached this script to a gameobject that is a parent of the player

Comment: The button is disabled, or the button is inactive? (they are different problems)

Comment: no they are in two different scripts

Comment: The button just doesnt enable when the player is destroyed

Comment: Debug.log(Player == null); Can you log this ?

Comment: Try it and see what happened.

Comment: It wont let me. it says "Debug does not contain a definition for Log.

Comment: and you can see player reference in inspector if your script is monobehaviour.

Comment: UnityEngine.Debug.Log(Player == null); try this

Comment: Yes. and when it is deleted it says that there is missingGameObject

Comment: When I do the debug.log nothing happens in the console

Comment: Could you show your complete code you think is relevant to the issue ... currently it is quite hard to understand what is supposed to happen vs what happens instead ...

Comment: I will edit the question then

Comment: is that better?

Comment: nothing happens in the console <-- if nothing in console , probably Update() is not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you are checking if player get destroyed or not. However you are destroying trigger.

There must be a tag on player object use that.  On your trigger object use this code. Pass player and button on inspector.

```
public GameObject Player;
Public GameObject Button;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) 
{ 
  if (other.gameobject.comparetag("Player"))
  {
    Destroy (Player);
    Button.SetActive(true);
  }
}
```

For this to work both objects player and trigger must have colliders
and at least one of them must have rigidbody , and player tag must be Player

Comment: It works!!! thanks